# Finite sum that diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In my Math class we were discussing sums. There's sums with infinite bounds that converge but are there sums with finite bounds that diverge? Well I thought of this idea

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lim_{x\to k} \frac{1}{x-k}$$

But I thought maybe this example is too trivial. Is there a better example you could think of?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to k} {1\over x-k}$? (This is meant to be a helpful Socratic question.)

Comment: Why downvote? How can I improve the question? I just wanted to know about this

Comment: Fyi - I didn't down-vote: but please note that the limit you wrote isn't quite defined (it's $\pm\infty$)

Comment: Reals are closed under addition so a finite sum is always in reals, assuming each element is from reals.

Comment: the point here is that usually, when you talk about convergence of infinite sums you talk about the convergence as $n$ goes to infinity. In that sense every finite sum converges. Your example doesn't have a limit when $x$ goes to $k$, which is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of a finite number
of finite values is
itself finite.

So,
the sum of a finite number of values
can be infinite
only if at least one of them
is (or is in the limit)
infinite.